# I would like to add some headings for datatable which i need to export in excel but unable to add headings

Tags: c#, .net

[Here is the image I want in this format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKlOh.png)

[But i am getting the result in this format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVy5F.png)

public void btn_excel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
DataTable dt_m = blu.checkbusiness();

```
        if (dt_m.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Business_Name = dt_m.Rows[0]["business_name"].ToString();
            if (Business_Name.Length >= 30)
            {
                Business_Name = Business_Name.Substring(0, 30);
            }
            pan_no = dt_m.Rows[0]["pan_no"].ToString();
        }
     
        dt.Columns.Add("Date");

        dt.Columns.Add("Miti");
        // dt.Columns.Add("Bill No").DataType=Decimal;
        dt.Columns.Add("Invoice No", typeof(decimal));
        dt.Columns.Add("Buyer Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("Buyer Pan");
        dt.Columns.Add("ItemName");
        dt.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(decimal));
        dt.Columns.Add("Unit");
        dt.Columns.Add("Total Sales", typeof(decimal));
        dt.Columns.Add("Discount", typeof(decimal));
        dt.Columns.Add("Taxable Amount", typeof(decimal));
        dt.Columns.Add("VAT", typeof(decimal));
        dt.Columns.Add("Export Sales", typeof(decimal));
        dt.Columns.Add("Country");
        dt.Columns.Add("PragyapanPatraNo");
        dt.Columns.Add("PragyapanPatraMiti");


        for (int i = 0; i < dt_report.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add();
            DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(dt_report.Rows[i]["date_of_sale"].ToString());
            datenepali = dc.dateConvertToNepali(date);
            dt.Rows[i]["Miti"] = datenepali;
            dt.Rows[i]["Date"] = date.ToShortDateString();
            dt.Rows[i]["Buyer Name"] = dt_report.Rows[i]["customer_name"];
            dt.Rows[i]["Buyer Pan"] = dt_report.Rows[i]["customer_no"];
            dt.Rows[i]["ItemName"] = dt_report.Rows[i]["item_name"];
            dt.Rows[i]["Quantity"] = dt_report.Rows[i]["quantity"];
            dt.Rows[i]["Unit"] = "Pieces";
```

}

//Exporting to excel

string folderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\POS" + "\IRDSalesReportFormat Excel\";

```
        if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
        }

        using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
        {
            wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, "Ird Sales Format");
            wb.SaveAs(folderPath + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd ss") + "IRDSalesReportFormat.xlsx");
            MessageBox.Show("Your sales excel report has been export to document", "IRD Sales Report Fomat Export", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [SpreadSheetLight](https://spreadsheetlight.com/) via [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SpreadsheetLight).

Example to import a DataTable

```
public static void ExportToExcel(DataTable table, string fileName, bool includeHeader, string sheetName)
{
    using var document = new SLDocument();

    // import to first row, first column
    document.ImportDataTable(1, SLConvert.ToColumnIndex("A"), table, includeHeader);

    // give sheet a useful name
    document.RenameWorksheet(SLDocument.DefaultFirstSheetName, sheetName);

    document.SaveAs(fileName);
}
```

To set individual cell values

```
document.SetCellValue("B2", "Some text");
document.SetCellValue("C2", 123);
document.SetCellValue("D2", DateTime.Now);
```

Another library, [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus) where you need to read the license.

```
public static void Import(DataTable dataTable)
{
    var filePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, _excelBaseFolder, "Customers.xlsx");
    FileInfo existingFile = new(filePath);
    using ExcelPackage package = new(existingFile);

    var sheetToAdd = "Imported Customers Demo";

    ExcelWorksheet anotherWorksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault(sheet => 
        sheet.Name == sheetToAdd);

    if (anotherWorksheet is not null)
    {
        package.Workbook.Worksheets.Delete(anotherWorksheet);
    }

    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(sheetToAdd);

    worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dataTable, true);

    worksheet.Cells.AutoFitColumns();

    /*
     * For this to work, all cell headers must be unique else an exception is thrown
     */
    using (ExcelRange range = worksheet.Cells[$"A1:G{worksheet.Dimension.End.Row}"])
    {
        ExcelTableCollection tableCollection = worksheet.Tables;
        ExcelTable table = tableCollection.Add(range, "CustomerTable");
        // https://www.epplussoftware.com/docs/5.8/api/OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.html
        table.TableStyle = TableStyles.Dark8;
    }

    package.Save();
}
```

See also, my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/excel-spreadsheetlight-csharp) on working with Excel which has the code above and more.

Comment: i have created datatable dynamically and the heading of it starts from zero index i have tried using worksheet and adding title and required heading but no use the problem is i need to move my zero index column to some row below so that i can add headings using worksheet is it possible to shift or move zero index column to some row below?

Comment: Read the docs on which ever library you want to use e.g. SpreadSheetLight, ImportDataTable(row, col, DataTable, use header) while epplus wants the cell range first a shown in code like A1, change to the cell you want to start the import. I can not stress enough to read the documentation rather than me giving it to you and this will give you clear insight how things work.